# How to boost Mongodb search result based on Criteria given

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am working on the requirement where have write query in which if users enters any acronym of university(Ex: MIT) have to get the result from database. JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d68cdcac8acd826e6a386b2"),
    "name" : "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
    "acronyms" : [ 
        "MIT"
    ]
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d68ce0bc8acd826e6a45b29"),
    "name" : "Manukau Institute of Technology",
    "acronyms" : [ 
        "MIT"
    ]
}
```

User might input "Name" as well. I have written "OR" query for that.

```
db.getCollection('universityCollection').find(
    {$or: [{"name":"MIT"},{"acronyms":"MIT"}]}
)
```

Now my requirement is if users enters "input" and if it matches with `acronym` it should return it first after that it will return items which matches with `name`.

Current `or` query is not returning expected order.

Any pointers will help.

Comment: Could you add to the question an example of the resulting JSON you are expecting, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try below query.

db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
     { $match : { $or :  [{ "name":"MIT" }, {"acronyms":"MIT" } ] } } 
     ,{ "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "acronyms": 1,
        "sortOrder": {
            "$setIsSubset": [  ["MIT" ] , "$acronyms" ] }
        }
    } 
    ,{ "$sort": { "sortOrder": -1 } }
)
```

If you are not familiar with MongoDB aggregates, check the below links.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/